Ошибка aiogram 3, Failed to fench updates
Перешел на aiogram 3 и столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Failed to fetch updates - TelegramConflictError: Telegram server says - Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running

Я уже не знаю, что делать, облазил все ресурсы, которые только можно было, запускается бот по такой инструкции:
async def main():
    dp.include_router(router)
    await bot(DeleteWebhook(drop_pending_updates=True))
    await dp.start_polling(bot, polling_timeout=3)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Exit")

Может кто подсказать, как решить данную проблему? Буду очень благодарен

Возможно ли, что это связано с тем, что сейчас я раздаю интернет с телефона?

У вас запущено два бота на одном токене, именно поэтому вы всегда видите такую ошибку в логах. Возможно, вы пытаетесь запустить код, не остановив старый процесс.
Telegram server says - Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running
Попробуйте найти процесс в диспетчере задач и "убить" его, после чего запустить снова, должно помочь.

Спасибо за ваш ответ! Но я немного не понимаю, каким образом у меня на одном токене запущено более 1 бота, если я использую только что считай созданный токен, да и в диспетчере задач запущен только один проект, в котором и произошла данная ошибка

@ИльяВикин возможно, вы запустили несколько python процессов, посмотрите в диспетчере

Проблему решил таким способом:

Заходим в BotFather
Удаляем своего бота, в котором возникала эта ошибка
Создаем нового бота
Копируем токен и вставляем в проект
Такую инструкцию выполняйте, если на 100% уверены, что никакие процессы не запущены.

Ребята тоже дали хорошие советы, поэтому тоже можете попробовать

Столкнулся с той же проблемой. Причиной оказалось то, что я запустил одну программу и через CodeRunner, и через Terminal.
